# Lock SQL on Select

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table that serves as a Queue.

Basically, I have a multi-threaded process that reads the unprocessed items and acts accordingly on those items and sets a *processed* bit.  Let's say two processes are VERY close and [Process 1] reads the next item in the queue.

How do I prevent [Process 2] from reading the same item [Process 1] just read, if for some reason [Process 1] has not yet had time to set the *processed* bit?

**NOTE:** There's another entire process that adds items to the queue.  I don't want to restrict/block that process from adding items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
BEGIN TRAN
    SELECT TOP * FROM TABLE WITH (XLOCK, ROWLOCK, READPAST)
    UPDATE TABLE SET Processed = 1
END TRAN
```

The **XLOCK** and **ROWLOCK** lock the row that I've just currently read.  The **READPAST** will read past the currently locked row.

So, [Process 1] reads the top row and locks it.  [Process 2] will automatically read the next, *unlocked* (unread) row.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. How about including a `status` column in your table? Setting this to `1` for example would mean the record is being processed. When your querying for record to process simply ignore any with a status of 1.

Comment: I could, but my concern is that Process 2 may read the item *before* Process 1 has had a chance to set the status:

Comment: For example: SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE; UPDATE TABLE SET Status = 1... What happens if Process 2 executes the SELECT statement immediately after Process 1 and Process 1 hasn't had an opportunity to run the update statement?  Then the row is processed twice.

Answer (score 0):

You said there is a *Processed* bit. You can compare that every time a new item is read to make sure its *processed* bit is not set to 1.

If ***Process1*** is taking long time to operate then:
       1. Set *Processed* bit to 1 at the begining of ***Process1***  OR
       2. Create a new bit as stated above by Ash and set that bit to 1.

Comment: That's wy I gave option 1. In that case when Process1 takes up a item, first step it has to do is set up the bit to 1(even before processing). If you have transactions in the Process, put this logic before the transactions begin..... If there are no transactions occurring, then putting a transaction on Process2 will also solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column to the talble, lets call it processedId

Create a stored procedure which does the following :

Generates a guid.
Sets the processedId to equal this guid value where the processedid is null.
return all rows in the table where the processedid equals the guid you generated.

```
declare @processedId uniqueidentifier = NEWID()

update table set processedid=@procesedId where processedid is null

select * from table where processedid = @processedid
```

The key here is to do the update first then return the rows which were updated in this transaction.